# Need clarification on shouldVisit and visit methods of Crawler4j

Tags: java, pdf, web-crawler, crawler4j

I need to download PDFs from websites using Crawler4j. I am following [this documentation](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/wiki/StepByStepTutorial) to create two classes:

1. `PDFCrawler`
2. `PDFCrawlController`

Now, in my `PDFCrawler` class, I have a `shouldVisit(Page page, WebURL url)` method as follows:

```
public boolean shouldVisit(Page page, WebURL url) {
    String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase(); 
    return href.startsWith(crawlDomain) && pdfPatterns.matcher(href).matches();
}
```

Here, `crawlDomain` is the domain sent from `PDFCrawlController` class (e.g., `http://www.example.com`). And `pdfPatterns` is defined as follows:

```
private static final Pattern pdfPatterns = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(pdf?))$");
```

The `visit(Page page)` method in the `PDFCrawler` class starts as follows:

```
    public void visit(Page page) {
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
        if (!pdfPatterns.matcher(url).matches()) {
            System.out.println("I am in " + url);
            System.out.println("No match. Leaving.");
            return;
        }
//and so on...

}
```

Now, when I am sending `http://www.example.com` to `PDFCrawler`, the `System.out.println()` inside the `visit(Page page)` method is getting printed as follows:

```
I am in http://www.example.com/allforgood
No match. Leaving.
I am in http://www.another-web-site.iastate.edu/grants/xp2011-02
No match. Leaving.
I am in http://www.example.com/careers
No match. Leaving.
I am in http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/image-happenings1.png
No match. Leaving.
```

My question is:

1. Why is the crawler going to `another-web-site`? Didn't I restrict it from doing so in `shouldVisit()` method?
2. Why is it visiting pages from the same domain that are in fact images (e.g., `png`)? Didn't I restrict it from doing so in `shouldVisit()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Your `shouldVisit` function isn't getting called.  It doesn't have the right declaration for the more recent versions.  You're following the example, but the example is wrong.

The only parameter is the URL.  You can see it in the API [here](http://%20https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/shadows/unzip/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/3.4.1-SNAPSHOT/crawler4j-3.4.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar-unzip/index.html?help-doc.html).

Also, you can catch things like this when you use the `@Override` notation.  Java will tell you that you aren't actually overriding the things you are intending to.